# Signal R Core HostedService Updates

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to use ASP NET Core signal r to push notifications to a specific client based on if an update has been made to the database. I am mostly there but my issue is the function isn't running.

SignalR is set up in Startup.cs. I have the following:

`services.AddSignalR();`

`services.AddHostedService<UpdateService>();`

`endpoints.MapHub<NotificationManager>("/public");`

In my javascript where the connection is made I just simply have:

```
connection.start().then(function () {
        console.log("Connection started")
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
```

My UpdateService.cs

```
public class UpdateService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationManager, INotificationManager> _hubContext;

    public UpdateService(IHubContext<NotificationManager, INotificationManager> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"UpdateService Ran at: {DateTime.Now}");
                await _hubContext.Clients.All.CheckForUpdates();
                await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)    
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            
        }

    }
}
```

Then my NotificationManager.cs and interface class:

```
public interface INotificationManager
{
    Task CheckForUpdates();
    Task EntityUpdated(string entityReferenceNumber);
    Task NoChangesFound(string getLabel);
}

public class NotificationManager : Hub<INotificationManager>
{
...

public async Task CheckForUpdates()
    {

        var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        var connectionId =  _userConnectionManager.GetConnectionsForUser(userId);


        if (connectionId != null)
        {

            var lastCheckedTime = await GetLastCheckedTimeAsync();
            var updatedEntities = _db.Table
                .Where(e => e.EditedDate > lastCheckedTime).ToList();

            if (updatedEntities.Any())
            {
                foreach (var entity in updatedEntities)
                {
                    //await Clients.All.SendAsync("EntityUpdated", entity.ReferenceNumber);
                    await Clients.User(userId).EntityUpdated(entity.ReferenceNumber);
                }

                await UpdateLastCheckedTimeAsync(DateTime.UtcNow);
            }
            else
            {
                var getLabel = "Stringval"

                await Clients.User(userId).NoChangesFound(getLabel);
            }
        }   

    }
}
```

I'm unsure as to why the `CheckForUpdates` isn't being called or working. My UpdateService is being hit because the timestamps are being logged. It does step over the `await _hubContext.Clients.All.CheckForUpdates();` but just doesn't carry out the functionality. Am i missing something? I was using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/background-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0 as a reference but at a blocked point right now.

Comment: I think your connectionId is null

Comment: @PvriaAnsari It doesn't even reach the function when i put a breakpoint though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the code you provided, I think you are missing some code in your javascript client side.

You can try to add below code first, to check the background service works well or not.

```
connection.on("CheckForUpdates", function (user, message) {
    console.log(new Date().toUTCString()+ " ========= Triggered by the background service");
});
```

In the Console window inside the Browser Developer Tools, please the output message, it should be has some message like below.

```
Mon, 17 Apr 2023 08:12:13 GMT ========= Triggered by the background service
Mon, 17 Apr 2023 09:12:13 GMT ========= Triggered by the background service
```

It means the background job works well, and the signalr server invoke the method `CheckForUpdates` successfully.

```
// Monitor the server call
connection.on("CheckForUpdates", function (user, message) {
        console.log(new Date().toUTCString()+ " ========= Triggered by the background service");
        // invoke the server side method
        connection.invoke("CheckForUpdates").catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
});
```

Comment: Is this not redundant since we are saying `connection.on("CheckForUpdates")` and then again we invoke it. Isn't one "on" enough to call the process since we have a hosted service that is running every X seconds?

Comment: Change `await _hubContext.Clients.All.CheckForUpdates();` to `await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("CheckForUpdates");`, I think it could be easy for understanding.

Comment: I have changed it to this but what im wondering is. If the code hits `await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("CheckForUpdates");` then should it not then step into the `CheckForUpdates` function in my `NotificationManager.cs` class? Why do I need to reinvoke it if it's technically hitting my hosted service?

Comment: Hi @ScuffedCoder  `_hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync` is used for invoke the frontend method. I don't know what is `CheckForUpdates()` in your side.  And I believe it should be doing the same thing, you couldn't use  `_hubContext.Clients.All` to invoke backend method.